# Might have locked myself out

Tags: linux, shell

I recently installed zsh as my shell on my laptop, and was loving the change. As a result, I decided to add it as the default on my server. I edited my /etc/passwd to point to /etc/zsh for my user and root (on the server), then exited from ssh.

Except I forgot to install zsh.

Now I can't log in as root or that user. I DO have physical access to the machine, but I'd rather not hook up a monitor. I also have access to a normal user account and know the root password. How do I go about fixing this?

Shouldn't need to be mentioned, but I can't install zsh without root access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the -s flag on `su` to specify the shell, so you can use `su -s /bin/bash -` to get to root using the bash shell.

Comment: I'm getting "permission denied"

Comment: `sudo su -s /bin/bash -` if you're a sudoer

Comment: Missing a space in the command. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a remote command by ssh, including another shell. You'll want to force a tty allocation so the shell can properly run. You can then run a root shell or edit files as necessary using sudo as normal.

`ssh hostname -t /bin/bash`

Comment: Not working. Permission denied.

Comment: Interesting. Further experimenting seems to indicate SSHD restricts logins if the passwd-specified shell doesn't exist. The design reasons why seems to be some people/systems still use invalid shell for "disabling" a user. Apparently specifying a shell works fine only if you already have some other working shell.